# Initialize from row - Birt

Tags: javascript, dataset, row, birt

I want to take the value from the dataset and split it and each cell in the row I want to set the parallel information from the split string.
Is it possible?

```
var aud=this.getRowData().getColumnValue("someString").toString().split(",");

for (var i=0;i<this.getRowData().getColumnCount();i++)
{
HERE I WANT TO SET SOMESTRING[0]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible *this* way. But you can do it in a different way.

Your "Table" needs enough columns to hold all values.

For each cell in the detail row, add a "Dynamic Text" item. The value is a Javascript expression. Use an expression like this:

```
getColValue(row, 1)
```

Replace the number 1 with the corresponding column number in every cell.

Define a function (in the initialize event of the report) like this:

```
function getColValue(row, col) {
    // Handle undefined, empty or null strings gracefully.
    if (!row["someString"]) {
        return null;
    }
    var aud=row["someString"].toString().split(",");
    if (col <= aud.length) {
        return aud[col-1];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

You might also pass `row["someString"]` to your function in the "Dynamic Text" expression instead of passing `row` and getting `row["someString"]` inside the function.

In a similar way you could style your cells depending on the data: Use the `onCreate` event of the item (either the cell itself or an item inside the cell depending on what you want to do) and enter a script like this:

```
styleCell(this, row, 1);
```

Again, replace the number 1 with the corresponding column number.

The function styleCell could then be defined as (untested, but you get the point):

```
function styleCell(item, row, col) {
    var style = item.getStyle();
    var cond = someFunction(row, col); 
    // The columns of row   ^^^ can be accessed as row["ColName"] here
    if (cond) {
        style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this was helpful.
Is there a way to copy & paste the dynamic text boxes from xml source tab?
I saw that each element has an id so I don't know how to increment it.
Have any idea?

Comment: You can copy the item into each cell with the layout editor. Then siwtch to the XML source and increment the value.

Comment: the option of using "row["someString"]" syntax in initialize is not working for me.